# NASM 64bit gcc linker error. Relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.text`

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86-64, nasm

## Code:

new1.asm-

```
section .text
    global main
    extern printf

main:

    mov rax, 5
    mov rbx, 55
    add rax,rbx
    PUSH rax
    PUSH message
    call printf WRT ..plt
    add esp,8
    ret

message db "Sum = %08X", 10, 0
```

## Command:

`nasm -f elf64 new1.asm -o new1.o`  
Above runs without error 
`gcc -fpie -m64 -o new1 new1.o`

## Error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: new1.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.text' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

## System Specs:

Ubuntu 21.04 
Kernel: 5.11.0-34-generic 
Machine: x86_64 
Processor: x86_64 
Operating system : GNU/Linux

I have also tried to use what is discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126328/cant-call-c-standard-library-function-on-64-bit-linux-from-assembly-yasm-code)
What mistake am I making and how do I fix this. 
Also I cannot do -m32 because it returns
`cannot find -lgcc`
and I want to use 64 bit registers

#### Edit 1:

After reading this [NASM printf print 64 bit double segfaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60366720/nasm-printf-print-64-bit-double-segfaults)  I changed my code to-

```
section .text
    global main
    extern printf

main:

    mov rax, 5
    mov rbx, 55
    add rax,rbx
    mov RDI,rax
    call printf WRT ..plt
    add rsp,8
    ret

message db "Sum = %08X", 10, 0
```

It compiles and links but now I get segmentation fault.
I compiled with `gcc -fpic -m64 -o new1 new1.o` this time

Comment: Where does this code come from? Shouldn't you pass `printf`'s arguments through `rdi` and `rsi`?

Comment: Even if that did link, `add esp,8` truncates RSP to 32-bit so the `ret` would crash.  (If you hadn't already for leaving printf's first 6 args (RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, R9) unset.)

Comment: Anyway, it's not the `call` that's the problem (you're correctly calling through the PLT), it's the `push message`.  You can verify that by removing the `call` instruction to make a [mcve] of *just* the code that won't link.  It wouldn't be runnable, but bisecting your problem to see what the tools are choking on is a useful technique.  Anyway, `push` isn't part of a correct way to call printf on x86-64 with less than 7 args.

Comment: Also a duplicate of [How to push label in stack in a relocatable shared library which its objects should be compiled with -fPIC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51542401) except you don't want `push`.

Comment: if i remove push and use `lea rax, [rel rax]` then it compiles and links but it gives `segmentation fault(core dumped)`. Even if i change the esp line to `add rsp, 8` I still get segmentation fault

Comment: You have other bugs too, like in this case [glibc scanf Segmentation faults when called from a function that doesn't align RSP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51070716) not aligning RSP by 16.  Your current code, as well as not aligning the stack, is passing an integer instead of a valid `char*` as the first arg (in RDI)

Comment: You might want to look at C compiler output for an example (GCC Intel syntax has some differences from NASM, but the general idea of what instructions it uses will still be there.)   https://godbolt.org/z/PE5Ybh38c / [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Comment: Also, wait a minute, `lea rax, [rel rax]`?  Surprised that even assembles (using `rel` on a register, not a symbol), and you're definitely not putting a pointer to `message` into RDI.

Comment: oh ok a bunch of errors then.